# Unable to get values from react hook state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am new to react native and hooks. In my project I have declared two state properties and I want to get them inside a function. But I am not getting the value from the hook properties.In console it is writing [object object]

```
const Login =()=> {
  const [username, setUserName] = React.useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');

  callAPI = async ()=>{
    console.log('api called :' + username)
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `setUserName` somewhere?

Comment: You may want to use `console.log(username);` directly to be able to see what the object actually is.

Comment: how are you calling setUserName ?

Comment: You code seems incomplete please add the whole snippet

Comment: you might have other things wrong in your code, I tried your code in stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hmomr2 and its working well

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example of what it looks that you're trying to accomplish.

```js
function mockAPI(username,password) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(()=>resolve(`The API received username: ${username} and pwd: ${password}`),1000);
  });
}

function App() {
  
  const [username, setUsername] = React.useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');
  
  function callMockAPI(user,pwd) {
    mockAPI(user,pwd)
    .then((result)=>console.log(result));
  }
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        Username: <input type='text' value={username} onChange={()=>setUsername(event.target.value)}/>
      </div>
      <div>
        Password: <input type='password' value={password} onChange={()=>setPassword(event.target.value)}/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={()=>callMockAPI(username,password)}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution I made a mistake on this line onChange={()=>setPassword(event.target.value)}

now it is solved by this line

onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}